# SharePoint ONLINE List Traffic Lights Showing Code instead of color

Tags: sharepoint-online, css, html

I have a small list I'm testing in for traffic lights right now with 3 columns.

Title, column1 and traffic light

title is just a text column, column1 is a number column, and traffic light is a calculated column with a bit of HTML/CSS in it with the .

the code for traffic light looks like:

```
="<DIV style='font-weight:bold; font-size:24px; color:"&IF([column1]<6,"Green",IF([column1]>12,"Red","Yellow"))&";'>•</DIV>"
```

Right now its only working in part. I update column 1 with a number and it will return the line of code it should be not the color.

example: I enter 10 in column1 Traffic Lights return `:<DIV style='font-weight:bold; font-size:24px; color:Yellow;'>.</DIV>`

This should just return a yellow dot.
It will change depending on the number I enter but It's not showing the color.

Is there a setting or feature I need to turn on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft blocks the execution of custom markup in calculated fields in SharePoint Online from June 13, 2017 onwards. Learn more about [handling HTML markup in SharePoint calculated fields](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4032106/handling-html-markup-in-sharepoint-calculated-fields).

For the classic list view in SharePoint Online, we can use Client Side Rendering to render list view.

Information about [Client Side Rendering](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views).

A demo: Add the following script to the page for rendering “Status” column based on column1 value:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function () {
    var overrideNameField = {}; 
    overrideNameField.Templates = {};
    // This action will edit the “Status” field. You can change the “Status” to another column’s internal name.
    overrideNameField.Templates.Fields = {
        "Status": { "View": overrideNameFieldTemplate }        
    };    

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideNameField);

})();
function overrideNameFieldTemplate(ctx) { 
//get the column value.
var currentVal = ctx.CurrentItem["column1"];
   // Render the column
switch (true) { 
        case (currentVal<6): 
            return " <div style='font-weight:bold; font-size:24px; color:Green;'>.</div>"; 
            break; 
        case (currentVal>=6 && currentVal<=12): 
            return " <div style='font-weight:bold; font-size:24px; color:Yellow;'>.</div>"; 
            break; 
        case (currentVal>12): 
            return " <div style='font-weight:bold; font-size:24px; color:Red;'>.</div>"; 
} 
}
</script>
```

For the modern list view in SharePoint Online, we can use JSON to render the column.

Learn more about [using column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting).

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you this is exactly what i needed. I had to tweak the CSS a bit so it fit my column but this is great. Also thank you for the helpful links. They will definitely be useful in the future.

Comment: would you happen to know anything about recursive navigation and fly out menus. I'm trying to change how site navigation works buy using a recursive fly-out menu that dynamically updates whenever a new site is created. I found some articles online that require you to keep up a list but with a very large site collections with several sub-sites and pages it becomes unrealistic and  unreasonable to maintain.

Comment: For the new question, it's recommended to create a new thread. One question, one thread. If my suggestion helps you, please "accept" this answer as the best answer. Thanks.

Comment: Checked . and ill start a new thread